# center of mass block is larger than model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I try to display center of mass, the block is so much larger than my model and covers my model. How do I make it smaller?
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8792/center-of-mass-block-is-larger-than-model/) by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Each pink box represents the inertia for each link in your robot. That is, if your link were a box with uniform density, with the given inertial parameters (mass and moments of inertia), it would be that size. The point where the green lines cross is the center of mass.

If you think the boxes are too big, this means the [inertia matrix](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=link#inertial_inertia) has not been well defined in the model's SDF. You could check this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=inertia&cat=build_robot) on how to find inertial parameters for your robot.

For completeness, I should mention that from Gazebo 6, to be released in July 2015, the visualization of inertia and of center of mass will be separated. "View inertia" will keep the current behaviour, while "View center of mass" will display a sphere which represents a ball of lead with the same mass (some examples [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1445/com-visuals-based-on-a-sphere-with-the/diff)).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on 2015-05-22**:
thank you. I tried with smaller values fro inertia. The boxes become smaller.